# Ethernet 802.1x client -> WiFi AP on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: router, ethernet, wireless-networking, 802.1x

I have an Ethernet connection that requires 802.1x authentication (TTLS, MSCHAPv2, name+password).

My goal is to connect that to something that would then act as an WiFi AP, so I can use the connection on more devices (iPhone, notebook, etc.)

Would it be possible/good idea to use Raspberry Pi for this purpose? Or are there better-suited devices to do this?

**EDIT:** found some alternatives but because of low rep can't post more than two links...

- [OpenWRT + wpa_supplicant guide](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=19791)
- Carambola - works with OpenWRT (but probably not standalone?)
- Hornet-UB - works with OpenWRT
- Asus RT-N10+ + [OpenWRT how-to](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/asus/rt-n10plus)

**EDIT 2:** probably going to try TP-LINK TL-WR740N. It's a classic router, but can be flashed with OpenWRT, and the price beats everything else I've seen.

Comment: Why are you asking this here?  As far as professional systems administration goes, no, no you don't want to try using a Raspberry Pi for this purpose.  A better suited device would be a business or enterprise class AP from a vendor such as Cisco.  If this is more of a hobbyist question or a hacking project, that sounds pretty interesting, but this isn't the right place for that kind of question.

Comment: Yes, it's hobbyist question. What's the right StackExchange site to post this then?

Comment: Aha, SuperUser.com. Thanks for the migration!

Comment: There's also a Raspberry specific site. Did you solve the the RTC problem by adding an RTC module onto the Pi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 802.1x clients need to know the date and time... think certificates. PCs and smartphones have realtime clocks so they have no problem authenticating, but the Raspberry Pi and the home broadband routers I've seen don't have RTCs. You can't even do an NTP query in the device's boot script (before 802.1x'ing) unless there's a time server on your side. That shouldn't stop you though.